# Image display dependent on database call

Tags: mysql, image, html, conditional-statements

```
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, $query)); the IF MAYOR image is not working i guess there is a confilct with the original db call?
```

In addition to email reminders, you can also LEND WITH CONFIDENCE because I have have a VERIFIED ACCOUNT and neigh*borrow will GUARANTEE that I return this item or they will replace it up to $50.";
            }
          }
    ?>

this code tells the page whether or not to display some text... i want to display an alternate image to THIS ONE  IF THE CONDITION IS MET... borrowing power =mayor

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:160px;left:535px;"><img src="images/NEI_icon_color.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first detect the condition at the top of the script:

```
<?php
  $isMayor = false;
  ...
  if ($row['borrowingPower'] == 'mayor') {
    $isMayor = true;
  }
  ...
?>
```

then emit different html based on $isMayor:

```
<?php if ($isMayor) { ?>
  <div id="a">mayor</div>
<?php } else { ?>
  <div id="b">non-mayor</div>
<?php } ?>

...

<?php if ($isMayor) { ?>
  hey mayor
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: so  the top code could go anywhere on the page then the bottom code is where i could direct to two different images?

Comment: yeah, the top code should be at some place where it will always run before the other parts, usually at the very top

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/neighborrow/www.neighborrow.com/wanted_test.php on line 326

http://neighborrow.com/wanted_test.php?item=146#

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/neighborrow/www.neighborrow.com/wanted_test.php on line 7